# given a method that takes a method as input, get its class and method name

Tags: c#, classname

I was wondering if it is possible to get method and class name of an inputted function of a method. I'll try to be more specific:

I have a class `Form1.cs` in which i created this method:

```
public static void CalculateTime(Action<string> funcToCalc, string where)
        {
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

            funcToCalc(where);

            watch.Stop();
            var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            // gets the textbox name
            TextBox t = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
            // writes in the textbox of this form this string
            t.AppendText(funcToCalc.Method.Name + " executed in " + elapsedMs + "ms;\n");

        }
```

In this class I call this method in this way:

```
CalculateTime( Class1.CreateStuff, textPath.Text);
CalculateTime( Class2.CreateStuff, textPath.Text);
```

What I want to do is to print out something like

```
"MyClass1.CreateStuff executed in 100ms"
"MyClass2.CreateStuff executed in 75ms"
```

etc.

For now, my method prints out

```
"CreateStuff executed in 100ms"
"CreateStuff executed in 75ms"
```

which does not allow me to recognize the class of the method called.

Is there a way to get the class name in this particular case?

Note that if in my `CalculateTime` i call

```
System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

I get the string `"Form1"`.

Comment: What class do you expect for unanimous actions?

Comment: Calling `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;` from inside form1 of course will return form1..

Comment: I am just wondering if it is possible without passing parameters to the method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easiest way would be to ask for delegate's [`Method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.delegate.method?view=netframework-4.8) property that points to a method being executed.

Note that while it works for static and instance members, it doesn't necessarily make much sense when called on an anonymous delegate (when a meaningless name of a compiler-created method is returned):

```
using System;

public class Foo1
{
  // static
  public static void Method( string s )
  {
  } 
}
public class Foo2
{
  // instance
  public void Method( string s )
  {
  }
}

public class Program
{
  public static void  Main(string[] args)
  {
    PrintDelegateInfo( Foo1.Method );
    PrintDelegateInfo( new Foo2().Method );
    PrintDelegateInfo( (Action<string>)(s => {}) );
  }

  private static void PrintDelegateInfo(Action<string> funcToCall)
  {
    var methodInfo = funcToCall.Method;
    var name = string.Format( "{0}.{1}", methodInfo.DeclaringType.Name, methodInfo.Name );

    Console.WriteLine( "{0} called", name );
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Foo1.Method called
Foo2.Method called
Program.<Main>b__0 called
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use on the action itself the extention method GetMethodInfo(Delegate) in order to the MethodInfo for the delegate.
Assuming you are not passing an anonymous typed delegate like a Lambda function, you can use this MethodInfo to get the class type using DeclaringType like so:

```
public static void CalculateTime(Action<string> funcToCalc, string where)
    {   
        var miAction = funcToCalc.GetMethodInfo();
        var actionContainingType = miAction.DeclaringType;
        var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        funcToCalc(where);

        watch.Stop();
        var elapsedMs = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // gets the textbox name
        TextBox t = Application.OpenForms["Form1"].Controls["textBox1"] as TextBox;
        // writes in the textbox of this form this string
        t.AppendText($"{actionContainingType.Name}.{funcToCalc.Method.Name} executed in {elapsedMs} ms;\n");

    }
```